# Is it ok to take antacid tablet after drinking beer?

Tags: health, pairing, drinking

Once I had couple of large beers. After that I've got acidity.
So Is it OK to take antacid tablet after drinking beer?

Comment: Maybe edit question to list your specific concerns about taking an antacid after drinking?

Comment: @CKrug I've taken antacid couple of times but i didn't faced any side effect. Just wanted to know if it damages internal body

Comment: Every now and then if taking an antacid won't hurt, I would advise against long term use.

Comment: I took NexPro RD 40mg tablet. Any side effects of this tablet after drinking beer.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues, but some stuff says that taking alcohol might make acid reflux worse. If in doubt, ask your doctor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends... I don't see an issue with the standard Tums or Rolaids but there might be issues with ranitidine according to some studies.

http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/news/20000215/zantac-alcohol-dont-mix

> "The effect was striking," says author Charles Lieber, MD. In a
>   three-hour test period, conducted under conditions similar to social
>   drinking, the study showed that ranitidine can increase blood alcohol
>   content by 38%. Levels reached in the study exceeded the legal
>   drinking limit -- and the effects lasted up to two hours after
>   drinking stopped.

Answer (score 0):

(not enough rep to comment yet)

I've been prescribed Ranitidine and it says "AVOID ALCOHOL" in all caps, so you know it's important.

Comment: (ooh, I can comment on my own Answers though... neat!)

Comment: I always figured since Alcohol can hurt your stomach, and you've been prescribed medication for stomach problems, better to avoid it. But that side effect is pretty wild.